# submit to another url in ASP.NET RAZOR pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I need help , I need to submit an html form containing hidden fields to another URL the values of the hidden fields some of them are static and some of them are dynamic (from code behind ) in webform , now i need to do this from asp.net razor page , with the code I have, only one hidden field value is detected appreciate your help.. also if i can know how to submit to the the other url !
below is my code

```
     model class name : jcc

        [BindProperty]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string MerID { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string AcqID { get; set; }
       

sendto.cshtml

    @page
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model saderlexstore.Pages.Admin.sendtoJCCModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "JCC Required Info";
}





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>

        function sss() {

            document.forms["paymentForm"].submit();

        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" >


        <input type="text" name="Version" id="Version" asp-for="jccgetter.Version" />

        <br />
        <input type="text" name="MerID" id="MerID" asp-for="jccgetter.MerID" />
        <br />

        <input type="text" name="AcqID" id="AcqID" asp-for="jccgetter.AcqID" />

sendto.cshtml.cs

     [BindProperty]
        public JCC  jccgetter { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            this.jccgetter = new JCC { Version = "1.0.0" };
            this.jccgetter = new JCC { MerID = "0011223344" };
            this.jccgetter = new JCC { AcqID = "402971" };

        }

        public void OnPostSubmit()
        {

           JCC jcc = this.jccgetter;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure what exactly you are aiming at, but if you want to send submitted data from one Razor page to another Razor page you should you `RedirectToPage` with paremeters. For example

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }


        return RedirectToPage("./SendTo", new { version = Version, merID = MERID, acqID = AcqID  });
    }
```

And on the target page, you should have a `Get` method that accepts and processes the parameters

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string version, string merId, string acqID)
    {
        //Do something with the parameters
        return Page();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,in your `OnGet()`,you set jccgetter with a new JCC model three times,so it will be set to `new JCC { AcqID = "402971" };` finally.If you want to set the properties of `jccgetter`.You can set the properties one by one.And if you want to submit form to `OnPostSubmit`,you can use `asp-page-handler` in `<form></form>`.Here is a working demo:

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public JCC jccgetter { get; set; } = new JCC();
 public void OnGet()
        {
            this.jccgetter.Version="1.0.0" ;
            this.jccgetter.MerID = "0011223344";
            this.jccgetter.AcqID = "402971";

        }

        public void OnPostSubmit()
        {

           JCC jcc = this.jccgetter;
        }
```

cshtml:

```
<form method="post" name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" asp-page-handler="Submit">


    <input type="text" name="Version" id="Version" asp-for="jccgetter.Version" />

    <br />
    <input type="text" name="MerID" id="MerID" asp-for="jccgetter.MerID" />
    <br />

    <input type="text" name="AcqID" id="AcqID" asp-for="jccgetter.AcqID" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: First than you for your help very appreciated and i need to know please how to submit this form please to another url please.....

Comment: What do you mean how to submit the form to another url,another page, not `OnPostSubmit`?

Comment: i want to submit these values to a payment gateway using the form in the code , so that the user inserts there its credit card number , then i get back a response i can read and based on it update the db . so i was thinking like :   <form method="post" name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" action="https://aio.com/EcomPayment/RedirectAuthLink">